# How to have to sections that are side by side that works on both mobile and desktop

Tags: html, css

i have a site that works good on desktop but not in mobile. I need a side bar that shows my ads but in mobile i see the two sections are stuck together and i just basically need a differnt css style that works on both mobile and desktop

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blazeguides</title>
 
<style>
body {background-color: #8C8C8C;}
header {background-color: #FFFFFF; margin-left:15%; margin-right:15%; padding:3px; border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;}
nav {background-color:#FFFFFF; margin-left: 15%; margin-right:15%; height:50px;}
a {color: #FFFFFF;}
.content {background-color: #696969; margin-left:15%; margin-right:15%;height:100%; padding:5px; border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;}
.indent-1 {float: left;}
.indent-1 section {float: left;}
.sidecontent {height:100px; border: 2px solid black;}
.ni {border: 2px solid white; padding:25px; background-color:#000000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <center><h1>Blazeguides</h1></center>
</header>
<nav><a class="ni" href="index.php">home</a><a class="ni" href="rpig">Raspberry pi guides</a><a class="ni" href="http://github.com/blazetools">Github</a></nav>
<div class="content">
 
<section class="indent-1">
<!---------------->
<section name="sidebar" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; width: 150px; height:100%; border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 30px; margin-top:-4px; margin-left:-5px;">
    <iframe data-aa='1145045' src='//acceptable.a-ads.com/1145045' scrolling='no' style='border:0px; padding:0; overflow:hidden; width:150px;' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
<iframe data-aa='1145045' src='//acceptable.a-ads.com/1145045' scrolling='no' style='border:0px; padding:0; overflow:hidden; width:150px;' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
<iframe data-aa='1145045' src='//acceptable.a-ads.com/1145045' scrolling='no' style='border:0px; padding:0; overflow:hidden; width:150px;' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
<iframe data-aa='1145045' src='//acceptable.a-ads.com/1145045' scrolling='no' style='border:0px; padding:0; overflow:hidden; width:150px;' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
 
</section>
<!-------------->
 
    <section name="content" style="height:100%;color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px;">
        Hello, welcome to blazeguides. This site was made during my free time with many guides for different things. <br>
        Examples :<br>
        <ul>
        <li>Raspberry pi guides</li>
        </ul>
</section>
<!----------->
 
</section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it wouldnt let me paste full code the code is here --> https://pastebin.com/MCVFFuLe

Comment: Have you tried using `css grid`? That will allow you to display them side by side on a desktop and below each other on mobile.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please paste your relevant html and css to a code snippet inside your question. It will be a lot easier and faster to help. Make sure not to add any code that is not relevant to your question.

Comment: hey joeri any code that i can do? like im not 100% sure what a css grid is

Comment: Add `position: fixed` to your "content" section to fix your problem. You will probably need to spend some time cleaning up your CSS a bit. Many of your *inline* styles are clashing with your *internal/external* styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try css grid like this:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
  }
}

/** some extra css to make example more visible **/

.grid > section {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <section>Section 1</section>
  <section>Section 2</section>
</div>
```

Remove the `grid-gap: 20px;` if you don't want spacing between your sections.

Comment: this will work itll just take a little bit to get it set up to look the way i need it